# How to create directories from makefiles?

Tags: gcc, makefile, cygwin, gnu-make

Could you help me with the following code I have written?

```
VPATH= balll mall fall
OBJECTS= objj/goka.o objj/foka.o objj/hoka.o
exec/gola: $(OBJECTS)
    gcc $^  -o  $@  
$(OBJECTS): objj/%.o : %.c
    gcc -c  $<  -o  $@
```

What I want to do is: I don't have exec directory and obj directory and I want them to be created during the compiling of the file and save those files in their respective directories. Can I do that? Creating the directory exec and telling the gcc to save the gola target file in exec directory and same with the objective files.
Is there any command to deal with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `mkdir -p dir1 dir2` to the appropriate rule of your makefile, prior to compilation.

Example: (You'll have to modify this for your particular setup)

```
DIR = obj exec
VPATH= balll mall fall
OBJECTS= objj/goka.o objj/foka.o objj/hoka.o

exec/gola:$(OBJECTS)
    gcc $^  -o  $@  
$(OBJECTS): objj/%.o : %.c
    mkdir -p $(DIR)
    gcc -c  $<  -o  $@
```

Comment: sorry but its not working its juss giving and error saying  make goka.o command not found what to do

Comment: j.w.r the mistake is that you  have written mkdir without mentioning the dependencies the target files jumps to the dependencies as soon it see the dependency names

Comment: @karthik - Yeah, sorry about that, my example was sloppy. I'd instead  do what @eriktous recommends from the make manual.

Answer (score 3):

Try order-only prerequisites. (See [the make manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Prerequisite-Types)).